# API call via url in django

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to make an api call in django to a url.

```
#api call
url = "https://api.lemlist.com/api/team"
querystring = {"user":apikey}
response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
```

Lemlist shows that the following call can be made as follows, but its in a different language:

```
curl https://api.lemlist.com/api/team \
  --user ":YourApiKey"
```

https://developer.lemlist.com/#authentication

With the python call noted above, I'm getting a 400 error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`--user` in curl means `basic authentication`, so you need to use the [Basic Authentication](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) provided by the requests module.

```
url = "https://api.lemlist.com/api/team"
response = requests.get(url, auth=('', 'YourApiKey'))
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a great help

Comment: It's very odd, but this didn't work. got a 401 error.

Comment: did you put the : just before your API key ?